# Stellar.js element offset position

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, offset, percentage

I'm using Stellar.js a nice parallax plugin. Here's the link: http://bit.ly/XUs0oW

Wondering if it's possible to set offsets using percentages instead of pixels...

As you can see in this code for the first image I added an horizontal offset of -350px and a vertical one of -85px.

```
<div class="bg bgUp" 
     data-stellar-background-ratio="1.6"  
     data-stellar-horizontal-offset="-350"     
     data-stellar-vertical-offset="-85">
</div>
```

I'd like the proprieties *data-stellar-horizontal-offset* and *data-stellar-vertical-offset* to change (in percentage) relatively to the viewport size.

Any hint how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Stellar.js doesn't work with percentages:
https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js/issues/7

Maybe try some of the nesting ideas mentioned in this comment?